# Properties of External orthogonal sum of bilinear spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, bilinear-form

[image]

This is [Lemma 1.3.14](https://books.google.com/books?id=c27pCAAAQBAJ&pg=PA10) from Scharlau's book *Quadratic and Hermitian Forms*.

> **3.14 Lemma.** Let $\varphi$, $\psi$, $\varphi_1$, $\psi_1$ be bilinear spaces.
>   (i) $\psi\perp\varphi \cong \varphi\perp\psi$.
>   (ii) If $\varphi\cong\varphi_1$, $\psi\cong\psi_1$, then $\varphi\perp\psi \cong \varphi_1\perp\psi_1$.
>   (iii) $\varphi\perp\psi$ is regular if and only if $\varphi$ and $\psi$ are regular.
>   (iv) If $B$ is the matrix of $\psi$ and $B'$ is the matrix of $\psi$, then the orthogonal sum $\varphi\perp\psi$ has the matrix
>   $$\begin{pmatrix}
>   B & 0 \\
>   0 & B' 
> \end{pmatrix}.$$

In the proof the proof is omitted with the comment that it's easy.

Definition of external orthogonal sum is given in [Definition 1.3.13](https://books.google.com/books?id=c27pCAAAQBAJ&pg=PA10). The underlying vector space is $V\oplus V'$ and the bilinear for $b\perp b'$ is defined by
$$(b\perp b')((x,x'),(y,y'))=b(x,y)+b'(x',y').$$

[image]

First two result are clear since bilinear form maps to commutative field $K$ but for regularity if both form are regular then external sum is regular is easy to show but what about other way and about (iv).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is about the opposite direction for (iii).

$(V,b)$ is regular iff $V^\bot=\{0\}$; where $V^\bot= \{x\in V; (\forall v\in V) b(x,v)=0\}$.

We want to show that if $(V\oplus W,b\perp b')$ is regular, then $(V,b)$ is regular.

Suppose that $x\in V^\bot$. This means that $b(x,v)=0$ for every $v\in V$.

Then we also have $b\perp b'((x,0),(v,w))=0$ for every $v\in V$, $w\in W$ simply from $$b\perp b'((x,0),(v,w))=b(x,v).$$
This implies that $(x,0)\in (V\oplus W)^\bot$ and thus $$(x,0)=(0,0)$$ (using regularity) and therefore $x=0$.

We have shown that $V^\bot=0$, which means that $(V,b)$ is regular.

The fact that $(W,b')$ is regular can be shown similarly.

---

For (iv) it is enough to look at $b\perp b'$ with respect to the natural basis on $V\oplus W$ determined by the bases of $V$ and $W$. I.e., if $(e_1,\dots,e_n)$ is basis of $V$ and $(f_1,\dots,f_k)$ is basis of $W$, you simply take basis consisting of elements of the form $(e_i,0)$  and $(0, f_j)$, where $i=1,\dots,n$, $j=1,\dots,k$.

Comment: Why use of  (x,0) is sufficient why not any arbitrary (x,y) for bilinear form?

Comment: what is meaning of take element of form (ei,fi); taking element as (ei,0)(ej,0) for matrix B will work and (0,fi)(0,fj) will work for B' right.

Comment: @vsk1996 My mistake. I have edited the post.